# Allocate 2D Array Char In Structure

Tags: c

I wrote a function taking in parameter a structure of type History. The structure contains a char 2d array, whose size is dynamically allocated.

So here is the function:

```
void appendLine(Historique** hist, const char* str){

    int size, i, sizestr;

    size=(*hist)->size;
    sizestr=strlen(str);

    History* tmp;

    tmp=NULL;
    tmp=(struct History*)malloc(sizeof(hist));

    copyHist(&tmp, *hist);

    freeHist(*hist);

    *hist=NULL;

    *hist=(struct History*)malloc(sizeof(History));

    (*hist)->size=tmp->size;

    if(((*hist)->line=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*size+sizeof(char)))==NULL){
        printf("ERROR !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((((*hist)->ligne)[taille]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(str)+sizeof(char)))==NULL){
        printf("ERROR !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i=0; i<taille; i++){
        (*hist)->ligne[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(tmp->line[i])+sizeof(char));
        memcpy((*hist)->ligne[i], (tmp->line)[i], sizeof(char)*strlen(tmp->line[i]));
        (*hist)->line[i][strlen(tmp->line[i])]='\0';
    }

    for(i=0;i<sizestr;i++){
        (*hist)->line[size][i]=str[i];
    }   

    (*hist)->line[size][strlen(str)]='\0';

    (*hist)->size+=1;

    tmp=NULL;
}

void copyHist(History** dest, const History* src) {
    int i,j;
    (*dest)->line=NULL;
    (*dest)->line=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*src->size);
    for(i=0; i<src->size; i++){
        if(((*dest)->line[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(src-   >line[i])+sizeof(char)))==NULL){
            printf("ERROR!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for(j=0;j<strlen(src->line[i]);j++){
            (*dest)->line[i][j]=(src->line)[i][j];
        }   
        (*dest)->line[i][j]='\0';
    }
    memmove(&((*dest)->size), &(src->size), sizeof(int));
}

void freeHist(History* arg){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<arg->size; i++){
        free(arg->line[i]);
        arg->line[i]=NULL;
    }
    free(arg);
    arg=NULL;
}
```

So everything seems to work fine, except that when I add several lines one after another, the line at `index 0` doesn't show something correct.

Thank you very much for your concern

Comment: Can't you use `strcpy()` and friends? Also, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. Finally, format you code so it's readable, and try to post less code.

Comment: Extending to the comment above: why don't you just use [string concatenation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) and separate entries by newlines (or specific tags if they already contain newlines)?

Comment: The reason I don't use strcpy is that I read on the internet it's better to use mem*, but is it really? Sorry for the long code, but I thought it was the less I could post for it to be understanble

Comment: Are you trying to allocate an actual 2D array or merely an array of pointed arrays? Because the code you posted does the latter.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)*strlen(x)+sizeof(char)` is easily replaced with `(strlen(x)+1)*sizeof(char)`, which is more readable. The issue of `sizeof(char)` being always `1` is tricky if you ever plan to switch to `wchar_t`; if you don't, you can just use `1` instead.